# Php mail is working but getting the output in plain text format

Tags: php, email, text

```
 $to = $emailid;
 $subject = 'APPOINTMENT';
 $message = "<html>
<head>
<title>APPOINTMENT</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>APPOINTMENT</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>".$fname."</td>
<td>".$lname."</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
 $headers = 'From: info@myhostname.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: mymail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) echo "Mail Sent.";
```

I'm sending a php html mail with this code.But the problem is that i'm getting the email as plain text (I can see the HTML tags). So what is the problem? As far as I know's are the headers properly set.

Comment: I'd argue this isn't a duplicate of that question @Progrock - OP is setting the content-type, but then resetting the `$headers` variable.

Comment: Why does everyone insist to send simple messages like that as HTML message? It adds tons of volume, complexity and especially security risks _for nothing_.

Comment: @arkascha no sir i have an appointment form to trigger in mail once the appointment form is submited.But for testing purpose i am sending only two inputs.

Comment: Do you see the "Mail Sent" message?

Comment: And what about people who use an email client that does _not_ display HTML markup? Those are not able to make appointments?

Answer (score 1):

You're resetting the `$header` variable the third time you're setting it. The following should work;

```
$headers = "From: info@myhostname.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: mymail@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Comment: yes i changed but i am getting the tplain text as the output.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>APPOINTMENT</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>APPOINTMENT</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>karthik</td>
<td>gm</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @karthikgm I've reordered the headers correctly and added a charset value. Try this instead.

Comment: i tried your updated code but now i am not getting the mail

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `$headers`; Mail sent successfully in my side.

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
```

Into

```
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: i tried your code but still i didnt get in html format..i am still getting in plain text format. i don't know where i am wrong.

Comment: It's working and I am getting the `HTML` format mail. Please check in your end.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: hostname <info@myhostname.com>' . "\r\n";
```

I got the output now..Thankyou for all of your support